# AmStockChart panel title identification

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I would like to growl the title of the stockPanel being removed on clicking the allowTurnOff button

I am using the below Listener but it is not working.  How does amStockChart register the panel which needs to be removed on clicking a certain panels allowturnOff button

```
addListener('panelRemoved' , 'function(event) {                              
                growl(event.chart.panels.title);
           }'),
```

Comment: Try removing quotes enclosing your event handler function code. If this does not help, please show your whole code.

Comment: if possible than please provide code in fiddle.

Comment: @Sagar. My entire code is in R and not in Javascript so I cannot use Fiddle. I will try to explain what my objective is in the answer section as comments section does not allow too many characters –

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may ignore the syntax around the quotes as I am using the charting library through R but the concept remains the same.

Let me elaborate the situation.  I have multiple panels with allowTurnOff buttons. I want to trigger an action based on which panel the user decides to remove.  Hence I am using the panelRemoved event where the program should message me which one of the panels (either in terms of Index or Panel Title) was removed by the user.

The below works:

```
addListener('panelRemoved' , 'function(event) {                              
                alert(event.chart.panels.length);
           }')
```

PS:  Replacing growl() function by alert for convenience.

The above code correctly calls out the number of panels in my chart but what I want is the title of the panel that was removed.  I can definitely provide the code in R which is similar but not exactly like JS.

I am assuming there will be a loop which will run through all the panels in event.chart.panels.length and check which one of the panels was removed and then throw out something like event.chart.panels[x].title I guess.

```
addListener(panelRemoved,function(event){
  for ( var i = 0; i < event.chart.panels.length; i++ ) {
   if event.chart.panels[i].removePanel.enabled==true {
      alert(event.chart.panels[i].title);
    } else {
     return();
    }
})
```

Please let me know if you would still need the R Code

Comment: @Sagar.  My entire code is in R and not in Javascript so I cannot use Fiddle.  I will try to explain what my objective is in the answer section as comments section does not allow too many characters

Answer (score 0):

@ Sagar:  Since my code is in R and not in JS, I am unable to share in Fiddle.  But I can make a good attempt to explain the series of steps involved. As follows:I have an amStockChart with multi-panel.I have set the stockpanel property allowTurnOff = TRUE. Now you will find that a small remove panel button appears on the top right of each panel. Now if a user tries to remove a given panel using that small little button on top of each panel, the event=removePanel gets triggered.  I will use the addListener to catch this event and execute some logic.  In that logic, all I am trying to do is alert as follows "Panelx is successfully removed". So to do that, I need to know which panel did the actually close.  I want help building that logic which will identify which panel the user closed within the addListener(event=removePanel) and then throw out the alert.  Ideally I would like the logic to throw out the title of the panel which was removed by the user